# How to update the whole tiles incrementally?

Tags: openmaptiles

It took nearly 7 hours for me to download the whole tiles. [Production-package](https://openmaptiles.com/production-package/) shows that **Business PLUS** users can use the automated update service to update the tiles incrementally. But I can not find the tool or system. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With the higher Production package, you can download the smaller incremental set of map tiles - containing only the places which have changed since the last update (typically a week).

This allows proceeding with the faster updates, where your locally stored 60 Gbyte planet file is actualized by a script using a small downloaded incremental tileset.

Please contact us (OpenMapTiles.com) to get the access to this system.

Comment: how do you do automatic updates on production package? do you have a silent install procedure. thanks